# Programmatically determining if someone has responded to a calendar invite in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I would like to create a view in Lotus Notes with the status of meeting invites. In particular would like to have a view showing only invites that haven't been responded to. Dug around in the fields on the invite form but cannot for the life of me find where this is controlled.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Responses of invitees are stored as response documents to main invitation document.

Unfortunately, responses are not stored in a field of invitation document in addition. That's why you can't show invitees that haven't been responded yet in view.

You might write an agent and collect respondents in an invitation document's field and show the diff in view then.